# run the procedure with the data in the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to run a procedure with values in the table. How Can I do it?

```
select * from ztAkademiUser2

EXEC dbo.PersonelAc @CurrAccCode='2144346', @Name='BUKET', @LastName='DEMİRBAŞ', @IsBlocked=0, @WorkPlace='343300', @JobDepartment='35121', @Mail='buket', @Phone='0000', @Fotograf='Default.png'
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: @jarlh TBH, you can click on the image

Comment: you're all right. you can't help the picture. but this is not a solution. please try to help me instead of judging me.

Comment: @Yunus They are trying to help you by explaining you how to improve your question.

Comment: @Edwin Stoteler I know. But it's boring to get a similar response on all the issues I've created on the stackoverflow. A little more solution-oriented approach. Like you did..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

- Use a Table valued parameter (by far the best)
- Use a cursor

[Table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine)

You have to edit your stored procedure to accept a table valued parameter.
First create the table type

```
CREATE TYPE PersonelAcParameter TABLE   
( CurrAccCode INT
, NAME NVARCHAR(100)
, ... );
```

Then alter the stored procedure to accept the parameter and edit the queries in the stored procedure to work with it. (Needs to be readonly)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.PersonelAc
    @TVP PersonelAcParameter READONLY
```

Call your stored procedure with the table parameter

```
DECLARE @PersonelAcTVP AS PersonelAcParameter;  

INSERT INTO @PersonelAcTVP (CurrAccCode, NAME, ...)  
// your insert here

EXEC PersonelAc @PersonelAcTVP;
```

[Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql)

You can use a cursor to loop over query results and call the stored procedure for each row.

```
DECLARE @CurrAccCode int, @NAME nvarchar(100), ...;  

DECLARE PersonelAcCursor CURSOR FOR
// your query here

OPEN PersonelAcCursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM PersonelAcCursor    
INTO @CurrAccCode, @NAME, ...

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   EXEC PersonelAc @CurrAccCode, @NAME, ...;
   FETCH NEXT FROM PersonelAcCursor    
   INTO @CurrAccCode, @NAME, ... 
END   
CLOSE PersonelAcCursor;  
DEALLOCATE PersonelAcCursor;
```

Be warned that cursors are bad for performance, sql is much better at set based operations.